The extrude doesn't snap to the object when topologizing
So I've been following a tutorial about creating a character from sculpting to animating(retopology included). After i retopologize the head, i want to do the neck. The tutorial says i need to extrude the loop(ill attach some pictures), then scale it smaller for it to snap to the object, the  extrude again to the base. When i extrude, it doesn't go around the neck, all the vertices from the selected loop somehow go to the vertices i see in sideview (numpad 3). I'm using a shrinkwrap and a subdivision for the topology, and the mirror modifier is applied. Can you please help me?


Alright, so I found out why. My magnet (snap during transform) from the center up was activated. Make sure that's turned off.
